# Trying to install new SSL cert with apache graceful restart returns [OK], but website stays down

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble gracefully restarting the Apache service when a new SSL certificate is installed.

I have a AWS Elastic Beanstalk application that serves websites for multiple customers, each with their own domain. To enable SSL for each site, I upload de certificate files to an S3 Bucket. I've configured the whole thing so that SSL is terminated in every instance and not in the load balancer. This all works OK.

Now, I want to be able to add new certificates dinamically. A client can buy a domain and have it point to their website automatically. When this happens, a new certificate is generated (via Lets Encrypt API) and uploaded to S3. The final step is having a cron job in the server instance that syncs new files from S3 (via aws-cli), loads the new apache vhost file and restarts apache. The sync works fine, and the graceful reload seems to run ok, but then the sites are down. My script looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 1>>/var/log/httpd/cert-sync.log 2>&1
# start
echo "[$(date)]: ----------- Start Sync-----------"
echo "[$(date)]: Syncing certs..."
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/certs /etc/pki/tls/

echo "[$(date)]: Syncing conf..."
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/conf/ /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl-vhosts/

echo "[$(date)]: Attempting Apache graceful reload..."
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd graceful

exit 0
```

The log output is this:

```
[Mon Jul  1 20:09:01 UTC 2019]: ----------- Start Sync-----------
[Mon Jul  1 20:09:01 UTC 2019]: Syncing certs...
...

[Mon Jul  1 20:09:01 UTC 2019]: Syncing conf...
....

[Mon Jul  1 20:09:02 UTC 2019]: Attempting Apache graceful reload...
Equivalent Upstart operations: start httpd, stop httpd, restart httpd, status httpd
Gracefully restarting httpd
[OK]
```

This leads me to believe everything is ok, but then I visit the entire application id down (I get 503). When the cron job runs again, this is the output:

```
[Mon Jul  1 22:57:01 UTC 2019]: ----------- Start Sync-----------
[Mon Jul  1 22:57:01 UTC 2019]: Syncing certs...
[Mon Jul  1 22:57:02 UTC 2019]: Syncing conf...
[Mon Jul  1 22:57:03 UTC 2019]: Attempting Apache graceful reload...
Equivalent Upstart operations: start httpd, stop httpd, restart httpd, status httpd
Gracefully restarting httpd
/etc/init.d/httpd: line 60: kill: (10478) - No such process
Stopping httpd
stop: Unknown instance: 
Starting httpd
httpd start/running, process 14139
[OK]
```

So now I know the service *was* down after the graceful restart, even though the log said it was OK. I can't find anything on the apache logs. I can rule out that its a problem with the certificate, or the configuration file, because if I make an empty commit and deploy using the cli (`eb deploy app-ssl`) the websites are back on and the new SSL cert is installed correctly (I can visit the domain with https on with no trouble). It is also weird that it says the service was stopped and it started it again, but the sites are still down. A server restart from the AWS Console doesn't fix it either.

**What I've tried:**

- several versions of the graceful command, including:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd graceful
/etc/init.d/apachectl -k graceful
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
service httpd graceful
```

- running with sudo and without sudo

But nothing seems to make a difference. This only works with a fresh deploy, which I guess causes a new instance to be created and maybe Apache only starts after the new files have been synce (I have an ebextension file that handles the sync upon instance creation). I need to be able to reload the configuration on an existing instance to fully automate the process.

**I've been at this for 3 days. Any idea what might be happening?**

EDIT:
The AWS EBS app is running Amazon Linux 2, and Apache 2.4. Also, `apachectl`, `apache2ctl`, and `systemctl` aren't found. The only way I can even try restarting apache is with `httpd`.

Comment: `[OK]` in many start/stop commands just show that the order has been delivered successfully, not necessarily that it has been executed successfully.  At this stage your question does not seem really programming related, it is more a problem of server administration, so you should be more on topic on [sf] for example.

Comment: `httpd -t` could also be useful (aka `apachectl configtest`). it will at least let you know if there is a problem with your configuration files (that you do not show relatively to your TLS configuration parts)

Comment: You're right, I should've thought about serverfault. I didn't know that about the [OK] message, and the httpd -t doesn't run. Is there a way to move the question to a different site or do I have to ask it again?

Comment: You can not move, just recreate it somewhere else. Except if it is explicitely closed here by moderation and deemed to be useful on [sf] or elsewhere.